# (C#)interface with virtual method

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, virtual

I need a interface object`IMyInterface obj;`that can swallow all classes object that inherit from it, as my sample code that are working well but inside I need implement function I don't need because `IMyInterface` require it, I try these two ways but both failed:

1. create `virtual class MethodThatNotBelongToUsAll{}` and try `class ClassA_wrap : ClassA, MethodThatNotBelongToUsAll, IMyInterface` but receive error `class 'ClassA_wrap' cannot have multiple base classes`
2. change `interface IMyInterface` to `virtual class IMyInterface{}` but the line `obj = new ClassA_wrap();` show error `cannot implicitly convert type "ClassA_wrap" to "IMyInterface"`

can anyone help me with this? thx!

```
    interface IMyInterface
    {
        int Foo0 { get; }    //ClassA,B,C method
        int FooWrap(int F);  //ClassA_wrap,B_wrap,C_wrap method

        int FooA(int F);    // ClassA method
        int FooB(int F);    // ClassB method
        int FooC(int F);    // ClassC method
    }

    class ClassA                //Base Class, can't edit
    {
        public int Foo0{ get { return 1; } }
        public int FooA(int F) { return F; }
    }

    class ClassB                //Base Class, can't edit
    {
        public int Foo0 { get { return 2; } }
        public int FooB(int F) { return F; }
    }

    class ClassC                //Base Class, can't edit
    {
        public int Foo0 { get { return 3; } }
        public int FooC(int F) { return F; }
    }

    class ClassA_wrap : ClassA, IMyInterface
    {
        public int FooB(int F) { return -1; }     // I want to get rid of this line, but Interface require to imp this...
        public int FooC(int F) { return -1; }     // I want to get rid of this line, but Interface require to imp this...
        public int FooWrap(int F) 
        {
            return FooA(F)*10+1;
        }
    }

    class ClassB_wrap : ClassB, IMyInterface
    {
        public int FooA(int F) { return -1; }     // I want to get rid of this line, but Interface require to imp this...
        public int FooC(int F) { return -1; }     // I want to get rid of this line, but Interface require to imp this...
        public int FooWrap(int F)
        {
            return FooB(F)*20+2;
        }
    }

    class ClassC_wrap : ClassC, IMyInterface
    {
        public int FooA(int F) { return -1; }     // I want to get rid of this line, but Interface require to imp this...
        public int FooB(int F) { return -1; }     // I want to get rid of this line, but Interface require to imp this...
        public int FooWrap(int F)
        {
            return FooC(F)*30+3;
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IMyInterface obj;                 //I need IMyInterface object that can swallow all three classes depend on flag

            int flag = 2; // or 1 or 3

            if(flag==1)
                   obj = new ClassA_wrap();
            else if(flag==2)
                   obj = new ClassB_wrap();
            else
                   obj = new ClassC_wrap();


            //-----------------------------------------
            Console.WriteLine(    obj.Foo0);
            //-----------------------------------------
            if(obj is ClassA_wrap)
                Console.WriteLine(obj.FooA(11));
            if (obj is ClassB_wrap)
                Console.WriteLine(obj.FooB(22));
            if (obj is ClassC_wrap)
                Console.WriteLine(obj.FooC(33));
            //-----------------------------------------
            Console.WriteLine(obj.FooWrap(1));

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your Interface has too many methods to match to your class. Why not split the Interface into 2 separate Interfaces. You can inherit from as much interfaces as you want.

Comment: A better pattern would be to create one interface that contains just the methods that all the sub-classes need, and others that contain class-specific methods. Each sub-class inherits the base interface and others as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it over here : [Interface Segregation Principle](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/07/interface-segregation-principle.html)

i think you need to look one of `SOLID` whichis `I: interface segregation principle`

this principle says that create seperate interce if you are having method in interface, which you calss is not going to implement.

i suggest design like this

```
public interface IMasterInterface
{  
      //contains all common method 
      int Foo0 { get; }    //ClassA,B,C method
      int FooWrap(int F);  //ClassA_wrap,B_wrap,C_wrap method
}

public interface IFooA 
{
   //contians method related to A only
     int FooA(int F);    // ClassA method
}

public interface IFooB 
{
   //contians method related to B only
     int FooB(int F);    // ClassA method
}

public class A : IFooA,IMasterInterface
{
   //common method 
   //now this will have method related to A only7
}

public class B: IFooB,IMasterInterface
{
  //common method
  //now this will have method related to B only 
}
```

Comment: I agree with Interface Segregation Principle but I disagree with the way you implemented it. In ISP, you usually create several smaller and *unrelated* interfaces. You don't inherit them from each other.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - i updated my answer now class should inherite IA interface and IMasterInterface interface , this looks  fine to me ..and thanks for pointing it out

Comment: ISP is all about giving the *class* developer the ability to pick and choose which interfaces he/she needs. You take that decision away from them as you always force IMasterInterface on them.

Comment: Yes, Now I agree fully!

Comment: Thank you....but I try this, since `obj` is still `IMasterInterface` object, it show error `'IMasterInterface' does not contain a definition for 'FooA'`...any idea? thx

Comment: @DaveG - to access FooA you need to convert you object to IFooA..you cannot access it with IMasterInterface as it doesnt have FooA method